# cannot resovle struts filter after add struts2-spring-plugin

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, struts2

i going to integrate struts2 and spring by use struts2-spring-plugin,but after i add dependency struts2-spring-plugin,
i got this [image]

here is the error

```
[2016-12-02 11:48:42,010] Artifact Gradle : com.example : Struts2-Plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
02-Dec-2016 11:48:44.260 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Dec-2016 11:48:44.354 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
02-Dec-2016 11:48:44.557 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Dec 02 11:48:44 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
02-Dec-2016 11:48:44.651 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
02-Dec-2016 11:48:44.948 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 594 ms
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
02-Dec-2016 11:48:46.151 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
02-Dec-2016 11:48:46.151 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
02-Dec-2016 11:48:46.151 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Dec 02 11:48:44 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2016-12-02 11:48:46,182] Artifact Gradle : com.example : Struts2-Plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

this is build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.struts', name: 'struts2-core', version: '2.5'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.struts', name: 'struts2-spring-plugin', version: '2.5'

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.2.5.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'javax.servlet',name: 'jsp-api',version: '2.0'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

}
```

this is web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
<!-- here show that filter should have a mapping-->
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You haven't given us the error you received. Can you please add the error?

Comment: sorry,i added the error

Comment: Are you sure that the `struts` and `struts2-spring-plugin` are downloaded correctly?

Comment: Why do you name it as Plugin?

Comment: it seems that i have added  different version of struts2-core and plugins  lead to this.
i build a new project with same version and works.